# Type mismatch found when running Scala code

Tags: scala

Below code says Expression of type `List[Any]` doesn't conform to expected type `List[List[Int]]`

```
def tran(l1:List[List[Int]]):List[List[Int]] ={
  if(l1.isEmpty) Nil
  else
    l1.head.head :: tran(l1.tail) // Type mismatch is happening here 
}
```

Below code is executing fine with no issues

```
def tran1(l1:List[List[Int]]):List[List[Int]] = {
  if (l1.isEmpty) Nil
  else
    l1.head.tail :: tran1(l1.tail) // This is executing fine
}
```

Comment: `l1.head.head` is an Int. `Int :: List[List[Int]]` is trying to put an Int where a List[Int] should be. `l1.head.tail` is working because the `.tail` part is still a `List[Int]`, and `List[Int] :: List[List[Int]]` will compile fine.

Comment: What are you expecting as your output? I'm not sure what you're trying to do here.

Comment: I was trying to program transpose of a matrix without using any inbuilt functions such as map or transpose etc..

eg: List(List(1,2),List(3,4),List(5,6))


The first code i wanted to get the 

1 3 5

and second code to get 2 4 6

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting list of list, so you should add List to: `List(l1.head.head)`

```
 def tran(l1: List[List[Int]]): List[List[Int]] = {
     if (l1.isEmpty) Nil else List(l1.head.head) :: tran(l1.tail) // Type mismatch is happening here }
  }
```

Comment: I was trying to program transpose of a matrix without using any inbuilt functions such as map or transpose etc.. eg: List(List(1,2),List(3,4),List(5,6)) The first code i wanted to get the 1 3 5 and second code to get 2 4 6

Comment: `l1.head.take(1)` will do the same as `List(l1.head.head)` and is perhaps a bit neater.

Answer (score 0):

`tran1(l1.tail)` is of type `List[List[Int]]` ( the return type of `tran1`) and `l1` is of type `List[List[Int]]`.
But, `l1.head.head` is not a `List[Int]` type. It is of `Int` type.
So, in the first case, you are trying to prepend an `Int` to `List[List[Int]]` type object.
That is why you are getting type mismatch error in the first case.

Now in the second case, `l1.head.tail` is of type `List[Int]` and you are trying to prepend it to `List[List[Int]]`type object ie., `tran1(l1.tail)`. That is why no error here.

Comment: I was trying to program transpose of a matrix without using any inbuilt functions such as map or transpose etc.. eg: List(List(1,2),List(3,4),List(5,6)) The first code i wanted to get the 1 3 5 and second code to get 2 4 6

Comment: For this, refer to my answer to your own question here:   https://stackoverflow.com/a/52771734/9953316