# Matrix multiplication in Scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to transpose a matrix of size 3*2 by defining a empty matrix of size 2*3, how can i create an empty matrix?? I am missing something in the commented piece of code!!

```
type Row = List[Int]
type Matrix = List[Row]

val m:Matrix = List(1 :: 2 :: Nil, 3 :: 4 :: Nil, 5 :: 6 :: Nil)

def transpose(m:Matrix):Matrix = {

  val rows = m.size
  val cols = m.head.size
  val trans= List(List())(rows(cols)) // Int doesn't take parameter

  for (i <- 0 until  cols) {
    for (j <- 0 until  rows) {
      trans(i)(j) = this (j)(i)
    }
  }
  return trans
}
```

Comment: If you want matrices, you probably want random-access data structures. If you want to mutate them, then you need *mutable* random-access data structures. `List` is neither mutable, nor does it allow to access entries in constant time. If you wanted an array, then `Array.ofDim[Int](rows, cols)` is probably what you want. The expression `rows(cols)` does not make any sense (why should it?).

Comment: Why are not you using the built-in `m.transpose` instead of re-defining the operation yourself?

Comment: I am trying to learn recursion, so i am trying to avoid most of the inbuilt functions

Comment: Is there a way i can declare a 2D list of pre-defined size which should be immutable???

Answer (score 3):

When it is necessary to access elements by `index`, `Vector` or `Array` is more efficient than `List`s.
Here is the `Vector` version of solution.

```
type Row = Vector[Int]
type Matrix = Vector[Row]
val m:Matrix = Vector(Vector(1,2), Vector(3,4), Vector(5,6))

def transpose(mat:Matrix) = {
  def size[A](v: Vector[A]): Int = { var x =0; for(i<-v) x+=1; x}
  for (i <-Range(0,size(mat(0)))) yield for(j <-Range(0,size(mat))) yield mat(j)(i)
}
```

***Test in REPL:***

```
scala> transpose(m)
res12: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int]] = Vector(Vector(1, 3, 5), Vector(2,
 4, 6))
```